# PHP - Unexpected behaviour using == (equal) and === (identical)

Tags: php

I had the following in my code:

```
$mixed = array();
$mixed[0] = "It's a zero!";
$mixed['word'] = "It's a word!";   

foreach ($mixed as $key => $value) {
  if ($key == 'word') {             
    echo $value.'<br />';
  } 
}
```

The above would for some reason print both "It's a zero!" and "It's a word!". I was expecting it to print only "It's a word!". Why is that?? I feel like I am missing something important. When I was using `===` in the if statement, it worked as expected, in other words it printed only "It's a word!". I know there's a difference between the equal and identical operators, but the first example is not equal is it?

Comment: This is not a duplicate if you really read the question.  The accepted answer makes this quite clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`==` does the type-conversion for you before comparison.

When you did an `==` with an integer `0`, it converted `'word'` into the appropriate **integer value**.

**[`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)** returns **0** when supplied a pure-string, so 0 matched. The other was matched in string-context, and that matched as well.

---

`===` does **no such implicit conversion**, so it returned true only in one case, when the strings were actually identical.

Answer (score 1):

PHP variables have type.

`==` checkes equality after conversion to the same type, `===` also checks the type. Use `var_dump` to see what the real types are.

Answer (score 1):

See @Cthulhu 's answer above which is much clear.

Apart from that, here is a different example. 
[strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function returns the position of the `needle` from `haystack`.

```
<?php
 $pos_a = strpos('apple', 'a'); // a is in the first position.
 $pos_b = strpos('apple', 'b'); // there is no b.
 if ($pos_a){
    echo 'we got a!'."\n";
 }
 if  ($pos_b){
    echo 'we got b!'."\n";
 }
```

`strpos` return `FALSE` if the needle is not found. But you will see that php does not run any echo statement.

If you `var_dumo()`'d these 2 values, you will see that `$pos_a` and `$pos_b` contain `0` and `FALSE`.

`if` statement just failed because `0` and `FALSE` both are considered `FALSE` unless you use ===

Now try this:

```
 <?php
 $pos_a = strpos('apple', 'a'); // a is in the first position.
 $pos_b = strpos('apple', 'b'); // there is no b.
 if ($pos_a !== FALSE){
    echo 'we got a!'."\n";
 }
 if  ($pos_b !== FALSE){
    echo 'we got b!'."\n";
 }
```

Now you will see the desired result as it echos "we got a!".

Answer (score 0):

$a == $b    Equal   TRUE if $a is equal to $b after type juggling.
$a === $b   Identical   TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.

it looks that

if you check 0 against a string with == then PHP returns true:

php -r 'var_dump(0 == "statuses");'
-> returns TRUE

but not if your string has a number at the beginning:

php -r 'var_dump(0 == "2statuses");'
-> returns FALSE

from the specs I get it that it attempts a conversion - in this case the string to number.

so better use ===

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php